# Can I center grid items along the vertical axis (y) in CSS grid without collapsing the height of the container to the content height?

Tags: css, alignment, css-grid, vertical-alignment

I need to put a colored background on grid items and have the text element content inside of the grid items centered both vertically and horizontally, however, when I use the align-items or align-content properties the height of the grid item collapses down to the height of the content inside of it. This means the background color doesn't extend to the upper and lower edges of the grid item.

By default the grid item fills the entire grid area it is assigned to, but the content inside is aligned to start. Is there a way to vertically and horizontally align contents in a grid item without collapsing the height?

Here is the basic setup:

```css
.gContain {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.gItem:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="gContain">
  <div class="gItem">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gItem">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gItem">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I need to have the background fill the entire space, while still centering the text along the y-axis. Is this possible.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsbin.com/pekizorunu/1/edit?html,css,output) what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Yousaf no, because the height is still collapsed to the height of the content. In your example, the only reason we don't notice it is because the content is all the same height. If we were to line the elements up in 3 columns and change the font-size of one of the <p> elements, we would see that the height of the other 2 containers is smaller than that of the larger content.

Comment: @Yousaf this pen illustrates what I mean better: https://codepen.io/codemints/pen/XWdqpQL

Comment: Also, this is maybe my 2nd or 3rd question here, so I'm not really familiar with the format or how to create snippets, so thank you for correcting that. I just used the regular editor, highlighted my text and hit the code button.

Comment: @Yousaf it's similar to the example in the pen. I need columns of different sized content to have the same height with a alternating colored backgrounds, but right now, centering the text causes the height to collapse to the max-content, so the background doesn't fill the container.

Comment: See [this demo](https://jsbin.com/yiyukegaxe/1/edit?css,output) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Yousaf That works great and doesn't require additional elements like my solution. I ended up wrapping the inner contents of the grid item in a div and positioning the grid item to relative and the inner div to absolute, top: 50%, transform: translateY(-50%). Your solution achieves what I wanted without the additional inner div element and 6 extra lines of code. THANK YOU!